# Why timer_create falls at linux

Tags: c, linux

I'm new at Linux,
I try to call the timer_create function, but it fails and I get the following message:

> `"*** glibc detected *** ...: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x085d0b0".`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>

int StartClock(Struct* pThis)
{
struct sigevent se;
int ret;

se.sigev_notify      = SIGEV_THREAD;
se.sigev_signo       = SIGRTMIN;
se.sigev_value.sival_ptr = pThis->timerid;
se.sigev_notify_function = ClockHandler;

timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &se, pThis->timerid);
return ret;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: please provide a more complete example of what you're doing. like the whole function, or at least enough code to compile and reproduce the error. I'm missing the `timerid` declaration and your used includes for example.

Comment: Use valgrind.  It will tell you the first place your code has done something wrong with memory access--and it may not be in this area of the code at all.

Comment: the timerid declered as timer_t, the includes are of sure ok. The function contain just this code for now.
i work on virtual machine.
i cannot use valgrind, but, using printfs i know that the problem is in the timer_create call.

Comment: You can use `valgrind`  on virtual machines. The bug is not in the code chunk you are showing, but elsewhere and before. The problem is not in `timer_create`

Comment: I didn't want to see the includes because I think you did it wrong, but because if you would provide a compiling code snippet, we could try it out and poke at it with debuggers ourselves.

Comment: While I agree with @JohnZwinck and Basile (why the hell can't I (AT)-link two users at once -_-) you could use valgrind to find memory leaks and pointer abuse, keep in mind that tools like valgrind only "guess" if memory was leaked or pointers were abused, and for example if you are writing a QT application, these guesses will fail, because QT (and some other big frameworks) rely on their own memory handling (e.g. with `QVariant` types you get a whole lot of invalid pointers, but the class prevents you from accessing them accidentally) which tools like valgrind can't hook properly.

Comment: Still doesn't show where `timerid` is set. You said it's a `timer_t`, but it looks like you're using it as a `timer_t*`?

Comment: You right, timerid sets in the header file, in struct Struct.
i tried to change it and i sent it as &pThis->timerid, but it doesn't matter anything..
but you right.